# What are common mistakes when creating mosaic datasets?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, mosaic

I have a set of images taken from a unmanned air vehicle, they have lat/lngs when properties are clicked in windows, but when they are imported into ArcGIS they have no spatial reference or coordinate reference system.  I have tried projecting the images in WGS and a state plane projection, but still no luck.  The images are taken at 1CM resolution on one day. When an actual mosaicked data set is completed, my output is usually the last data set that was uploaded into the dataset, hence I have a footprint around one image instead of multiple images.

As far as typical workflow:

Should the images be projected, then assembled into a mosaic dataset?

When should I use a raster dataset or raster catalog to assemble a mosaic dataset?

I will have upwards to 100 or more images that will need to be mosaicked.

I am using ArcGIS 10.2

Comment: It sounds like you need to define the projection when you import the images into ArcGIS: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000077000000

Comment: how many lat/longs do you have in Windows. Maybe this is only the position of your UAV when it took the image, in which case you still need to orthorectify the images.